# Bluemix Default Organization

Tags: ibm-cloud, administration

Is there a way to change the default organization in Bluemix?  Right now every time I login to Bluemix, the organization listed is my teammate's org.  I want to have Bluemix default to my organization.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bluemix saves your configuration (organization and space) in a browser cookie.

The first time you login it will default to first organization in alphabetical order and the first space in alphabetical order within that organization.

After you change to your preferred organization and space and logout from Bluemix, the next time you login Bluemix will default to the new organization and space.

The only exception is if you are using a private or incognito browser that will disable cookies or if you delete your cookies, in which case it will default again to the organization using alphabetical order.

Comment: Ah thanks, there's my problem.  I always delete my cookies.  Thanks!